# React efficiently update object in array with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component that renders a moderately large list of inputs (100+ items). It renders okay on my computer, but there's noticeable input lag on my phone. The React DevTools shows that the entire parent object is rerendering on every keypress.

Is there a more efficient way to approach this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMvoyy?editors=0011

```
function MyInput({obj, onChange}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        {obj.label}
        <input type="text" value={obj.value} onChange={onChange} />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

// Passed in from a parent component
const startingObjects = 
  new Array(100).fill(null).map((_, i) => ({label: i, value: 'value'}));

function App() {
  const [objs, setObjects] = React.useState(startingObjects);
  function handleChange(obj) {
    return (event) => setObjects(objs.map((o) => {
      if (o === obj) return {...obj, value: event.target.value}
      return o;
    }));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {objs.map((obj) => <MyInput obj={obj} onChange={handleChange(obj)} />)}  
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling your function instead of passing it. `onChange={handleChange(obj)} ` should be `onChange={() => handleChange(obj)}`

Comment: A key for `<MyInput />` is also missing

Comment: @DCTID handleChange is currying the event function. So while invoked, will return a function to handle the event function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is related to:

```
function handleChange(obj) {
  return (event) => setObjects(objs.map((o) => {
    if (o === obj) return {...obj, value: event.target.value}
    return o;
  }));
}
```

In this, you will update the `objs` array. This is obviously fine, but React doesn't know what has changed, so triggered Render on all the Children.

If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

```
const MyInput = React.memo(({obj, onChange}) => {
    console.log(`Rerendered: ${obj.label}`);
    return <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <label>{obj.label}</label>
        <input type="text" value={obj.value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>;
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.obj.label === nextProps.obj.label && prevProps.obj.value === nextProps.obj.value);
```

However, React.Memo only does a shallow comparison when trying to figure out if it should render, so we can pass a custom comparison function as the second argument.

```
(prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.obj.label === nextProps.obj.label && prevProps.obj.value === nextProps.obj.value);
```

Basically saying, if the label and the value, on the `obj` prop, are the same as the previous attributes on the previous `obj` prop, don't rerender.

Finally, `setObjects` much like setState, is also asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect and update. So to avoid the risk of `objs` being incorrect, and using the older values, you can change this to a callback like so:

```
function handleChange(obj) {
  return (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setObjects(prevObjs => (prevObjs.map((o) => {
      if (o === obj) return {...obj, value }
      return o;
    })))
  };
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPBLwy?editors=0011 has all this, as well as console.logs, showing if something rerendered.

---

> Is there a more efficient way to approach this?

You are storing all your values in an array, which means you don't know which element needs to be updated without iterating through the whole array, comparing if the object matches.

If you started with an Object:

```
const startingObjects = 
  new Array(100).fill(null).reduce((objects, _, index) => ({...objects, [index]: {value: 'value', label: index}}), {})
```

After some modifications, your handle function would change to

```
function handleChange(obj, index) {
  return (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setObjects(prevObjs => ({...prevObjs, [index]: {...obj, value}}));
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvBPEB?editors=0011 as an example of this.

Comment: I was just finishing my tests to post nearly the same answer. Good answer!

Comment: This answer is amazing. Memo finally makes sense. I am still not able to get it working. The comparison function isn't getting invoked. I'll try to get a CodePen, but of note is that I'm still using an array with an update function like this:
`setObjects(prev => prev.fill({...prev[i], value},i,i+1))`
which replaces the item at a specific index with itself after getting the new value.

Comment: Here's a version that doesn't work. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMmVaB?editors=0011 The real kicker is that it works in react 16.7.0-alpha, but I updated to 16.8 and no dice. Does that mean its a bug in react?

Comment: _updateObjInArr_ is mutating the `prev` state. So React thinks the state never changed as you are accidentally updating the previous state to match the new state. Change it to `arr.slice().fill(......` and it will work